# Seg Fault with argument 4 of pthread_create()

Tags: c, pthreads

I got an error message of Segmentation fault (core dump) when I try to run this code.
Note: This is a really long program (almost 600 lines) so I only posted the ones that I 'think' is related. Let me know if more needed? Thanks in advance :)

```
#define CONSTANT 4

int main()
{
  pthread_t tid[CONSTANT];
  int i, check;
  for( i = 0; i < CONSTANT; i++ )
  {
     check = pthread_create( &tid[i], NULL, tFunction, (void *) CONSTANT );
  }
}

void * tFunction ( void * param )
{
  int num = * (int *) param;  /* Seg fault line */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is:

`check = pthread_create( &tid[i], NULL, tFunction,`**`(void *) 4`**`);`

And treating the 4th argument as an `int *`, which it obviously isn't. When you dereference **the address 4** in `tFunction` you get a segfault.

If you want to pass a pointer to an `int` with a value of 4, pass the address of an `int` variable, ie:

```
#include <pthread.h>

#define CONSTANT 4

void * tFunction ( void * param )
{
  int num = * (int *) param;  /* Seg fault line */
}

int main(void)
{
  int arg = CONSTANT;
  pthread_t tid[CONSTANT];
  int i, check;
  for( i = 0; i < CONSTANT; i++ )
  {
     check = pthread_create( &tid[i], NULL, tFunction, (void *) &arg );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: `pthread_join` is going to be useful so that you can wait for your threads to terminate before exiting your program.

**EDIT2**: If you haven't read the comments: You should ensure that if your passing a local variable (as with this example which was meant to show a very minor change to his code to get it working) that any new threads finish before the variable goes out of scope with the use of `pthread_join`, or to dynamically allocate memory for the variable on the heap.

Comment: Be warned that passing a pointer to a local variable is potentially dangerous depending on the lifetime of the calling function.

Comment: Yeah true, just in this example it'd make no difference.

Comment: Oh yea! that's what I was doing :) I played around and forgot to change it back in my code lol. Anyways, that gave me an error: lvalue required as unary operand. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dino55, are you trying to do `&CONSTANT`?  That won't work.  Use @AusCBloke's example exactly and you should be fine.

Comment: @Dino55 it should compile as is with the `<pthread.h>` header: `gcc -pthread -o ...`.

Comment: @AusCBloke, ohh. sorry! i read your response too fast and didn't see that you actually saved the CONSTANT in a local variable >.< Hell yea! that total saved my program :) Thank you guys so much!!

Comment: @Carl, Yep. I was trying to do &CONSTANT. It looked weird to me too. I tried to look for the um.. Data Type(?) of a constant online, but I found nothing ..

Comment: Also, take note of Carl's comment. If you're expecting your threads to continue executing after the life of the function calling them, then you're going to want to allocate memory for them on the heap. Variables in main are *usually* fine, you might also want to `pthread_wait` so that you can wait for your threads to exit before terminating the program.

Comment: I have pthread_exit(NULL); at the end of tFunction and a FOR loop that pthread_join( tid[j], NULL ); in the main()  Are these enough?

Comment: Woops yeah it's `pthread_join` I'm talking about. You could use `pthread_exit(NULL)` or `return NULL`, not too much of a difference, up to you. I usually use `return NULL`.

Comment: This answer, as written, is very bad. It invokes UB because `arg` may be accessed by the newly created thread after it goes out of scope! You need some synchronization to prevent this, or preferably use Carl's answer that does not suffer from the issue.

Comment: @R.. I already told him that through the comments; to use `pthread_join` before `arg` goes out of scope or to `malloc` some memory on the heap. The idea of the answer was to demonstrate the minor mistake he was making with his code. Anyhow, I added a note to the answer because you're right, the answer as is `could` lead to problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to cast a constant to `void *` and pass it in as your context parameter, you need to do the complementary operation on the other end:

```
int num = (intptr_t)param;
```

Should do it for you.  Your current program has an extra dereference, which ends up doing something like this:

```
int num = *(int *)4;
```

and that's what's crashing your program right now.

Comment: Warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size. Is what I got from it. How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: @Dino55 - `int` isn't the same size as a pointer on your platform. I've updated my answer with the C99 `intptr_t` type from `stdint.h`.  If that doesn't work, you can just use `long`.